# "The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing." in GitHub Actions

Tags: cypress, github-actions

I'm receiving the following error when running a Cypress e2e test runner on GitHub Actions:

```
The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.

We expected the binary to be installed here: /home/runner/.cache/Cypress/8.5.0/Cypress/Cypress

Reasons it may be missing:

- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /home/runner/.cache/Cypress
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: /home/runner/.cache/Cypress
```

My `.github/workflow/tests.yml` is set up as follows:

```yaml
name: celestia/tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - master

jobs:
  unit:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node: [14]

    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      # Setup .npmrc file to publish to GitHub Packages
      - name: Setup node env  and .npmrc file to publish to GitHub Packages
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          # Defaults to the user or organization that owns the workflow file:
          scope: '@observerly'

      - name: Cache node_modules 
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Install project dependencies ‍
        run: npm ci --ignore-scripts

      - name: Run jest unit tests 
        run: npm run test:unit

  e2e:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node: [14]

    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      # Setup .npmrc file to publish to GitHub Packages
      - name: Setup node env  and .npmrc file to publish to GitHub Packages
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          # Defaults to the user or organization that owns the workflow file:
          scope: '@observerly'

      - name: Install project dependencies ‍
        run: npm ci --ignore-scripts

      - name: Run e2e cypress tests 
        run: npm run test:e2e:headless
```

How can I side-step this particular issue?

Comment: Why do you `--ignore-scripts`? That prevents Cypress installing the binary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So that my NODE_AUTH_TOKEN / NPM_TOKEN secrets aren't exposed a potentially malicious npm package ...

Comment: Well now you see the downside - some of your dependencies might need those scripts to run. You'll have to "manually" download the correct Cypress binary and configure the path to it, but there may be other similar issues that crop up.

Comment: Yeh ... very true. I have removed this flag as I have a health checker on malicious npm packages running as well ... I guess I could have an action that `npm installs cypress` after this to cache them?

Comment: Note you don't necessarily have to expose those as env vars to the whole job, you can look into read-only tokens for install, and having a matrix for a single Node version is a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If Cypress is installed through `npm ci` with the option `--ignore-scripts` then the postinstall script of Cypress will not be executed.

```bash
npx cypress install
```

will install the Cypress binary after using `npm ci --ignore-scripts` has been run.

Since the Cypress binary zip file is around 200MB in size it may be advisable to cache it for future CI/CD runs.